# Crear un built-in aplicable a cualquier lista o tupla

Tags: python, lista, funciones, class, tuplas

Tengo creada una función que calcula a qué distancia se encuentra el elemento más lejano en una lista y quiero convertirlo en un built-in para poder aplicarlo cada vez que lo necesite en una lista o una tupla con **"lista|tupla.depth"**.

Obviamente, podría hacerlo simplemente pasando la lista como argumento pero os paso un ejemplo simple y corto para no daros más trabajo.

He probado creando una clase list que hereda object pero no ha habido resultados, aparte he estado buscando y no he encontrado información relevante al respecto en Internet, ¿es acaso esto posible?

Código de la función:

```
def depth(lista: list, all_non_empty_child: bool = False, counter=0):
    count=[]
    def guess_depth(lista, counter=0):
        for sublista in lista:
            if isinstance(sublista, list) or isinstance(sublista, tuple):
                count.append(counter+1)
                repetir=guess_depth(sublista, counter+1)
        return counter
    guess_depth(lista)
    max_depth = max(count)
    duplicated_depths = duplicated(count)

    return max_depth if count and not(all_non_empty_child) else list(zip((d for d in duplicated_depths if d!=max_depth), (max_depth,)))[0] if count and duplicated_depths else 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible, aunque no del todo.

##### Solución

Las listas son builtins, por lo que no es posible modificar sus atributos, lo cual descarta el monkey patching.

Sin embargo, podemos hacer una clase Lista que derive de list (la clase que representa una lista en python), agregar el método deseado y reemplazar el builtin list por Lista modificando el módulo builtins, el cual guarda los builtins de Python. Finalmente, repetimos el mismo procedimiento con la tupla.

Ejemplo de código:

```
class Lista(list):
    def contains(obj):
        print("La", type(obj).__name__, "contiene", ", ".join(map(repr, obj)))

import builtins

builtins.__dict__["list"] = Lista
```

Una vez ejecutado este código, los PROXIMOS intentos de crear una lista con list, usará nuestra clase Lista, incluso en otros modulos (comportamiento probablemente no deseado, ver más abajo)

**Sin embargo**, escribir una lista o tupla de la forma "convencional", es decir `[1, 2, 3]` o `(1, 2, 3)` devolverá una instancia de list o tuple común y corriente, ya que python internamente no hace uso del modulo builtins para crear la lista. Presumiblemente, usa la api de Python en c.

##### ¿Esto es buena idea?

No soy experto, pero no creo que sea buena idea reemplazar un builtin para todo un programa de Python (a menos que quieras hacer monkey patching por un buen motivo). Esto por que si llegases a "reemplazar" un solo método de list o tuple  por uno tuyo (ejemplo, `__contains__`, que ya existe en listas y tuplas), un módulo que llame a list, obtendrá una instancia de la clase Lista y habría comportamientos inesperados.

Por ejemplo, ponele que primero importas un módulo a con el código (notese los guiones bajos alrededor de contains):

```
class Lista(list):
    def __contains__(obj):
        return True

import builtins

builtins.__dict__["list"] = Lista
```

Y luego importas un modulo b (el código no es optimizado, es solo un ejemplo):

```
if 4 in list({1, 2, 3}):
    ...
```

Usará nuestro método contains, que siempre devuelve True y el condicional dará verdadero a pesar de que el 4 no está en la lista.

##### La mejor altenativa en mi opinión

No trates de pasarlo como builtin, en su lugar, guarda tu subclase de lista en un archivo py (ejemplo, `mycollections.py`), y siempre que requieras usar a la clase Lista, podrás obtenerla con `from mycollections import Lista`. Notese que la forma de importar Lista varía dependiendo de la ubicación de MyCollections. Pero eso ya es tema para otra pregunta.